# Web Service that handles file upload works locally but not remote

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

I've written a webservice in ServiceStack that accepts file uploads.
To test it I've used the following code:

```
string filePath = @"C:\myFile.pdf";
string webApi = @"http://localhost:20938/upload/myFile.pdf";

HttpWebRequest client = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webApi);
client.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
client.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
client.SendChunked = true;
client.ContentType = "multipart/form-data;";
client.Timeout = int.MaxValue;

using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
{
    fileStream.Copy(client.GetRequestStream());
}

var response = new StreamReader(client.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

This works with localhost, but when I deploy it to a remote server, it doesn't work. I get a 500 internal error. (Other Web API calls that return JSON data work perfectly locally and remotely).

How do I fix/debug this?

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: No. I tried AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true, and that didn't work. I haven 't managed to install the remote debugger. I'm commenting out code and deploying so I can pin point where the issue is. I wish there was a way I could get the stack trace.

Comment: Do you have servicestack logging ? Also Do you have a firewall, blocking the server's  port ?  can you write and the server's code ?

Comment: Did you try with different file sizes ?

Comment: There is no firewall blocking the port because other calls work

Comment: Shouldn't be file size problems because the files i'm using are 20 kb.

Comment: I'll try service stack logging...

Comment: Do you have permissions to write in the folder where you upload the file?

Answer (score 1):

The code below, works for me.
the only difference, I can see is the AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

```
            string requestUri = Path.Combine(serverIP + @"/upload/", filename);
            HttpWebRequest client = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
            client.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;

            client.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
            client.SendChunked = true;
            client.ContentType = "multipart/form-data;";
            client.Timeout = int.MaxValue;
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
            {
                fileStream.Copy(client.GetRequestStream());
            }
            var response = new StreamReader(client.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Do you have a firewall, blocking the port ?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue. The issue was with another part of the code.
I managed to find with through service stack logging.

Comment: This is not an answer.  We tried to help you and share our experience and you followed an advice for the ServiceStack logging. At least share your experience with few details to improve the common knowledge base, before you accept your own answer, so we can vote you also.

Comment: One of the 3rd party libraries I was using was on a 30 day trial. My local machine was within the 30 day trial so it worked. The remote machine wasn't because the 30 day trial had expired. I didn't know that because all it gave me was a 500. Using the logging, the error got logged. I asked the vendor for an extension, got and applied it, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Note: both the [ServiceStack C# ServiceClients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) and [HttpUtils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils#uploading-files) support uploading files - see [FileUploadTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/FileUploadTests.cs) for examples.